# Need to arrange a record using while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

While fetching details using while loop I am not able to get it as I want. What I want is to apply a loop and get details of each date. I am using SQL 2008.

```
    Set @i = 1;

    While (@NoOfDays >= @i)
    Begin

    SET @ManufactureQty = (Select isnull(SUM(Quantity),0) as Manufactured from IGN1 inner join OIGN on (OIGN.DocEntry = IGN1.DocEntry) 
    inner join OITM on (OITM.ItemCode = IGN1.ItemCode)
    where Convert(Date,Cast(OIGN.DocDate as DATE))  = Convert(Date,DATEADD(d, @i, @date)) and OITM.ItmsGrpCod = @ItemGroup)

    Select @i as D,OpeningBalance = case 
    when @i > 1 then ((isnull(SUM(OINM.InQty),0)-isnull(SUM(OINM.OutQty),0)) + ((isnull(SUM(OINM.InQty),0)-isnull(SUM(OINM.OutQty),0))))
    when @i = 1 then (isnull(SUM(OINM.InQty),0)-isnull(SUM(OINM.OutQty),0))
    end
    ,
    isnull(@ManufactureQty,0) as Manufacture
    From OITM
    Inner Join OINM  On (OINM.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode and Convert(Date,Cast(OINM.DocDate as DATE)) = Convert(Date,DATEADD(d, @i, @date))) --and Convert(Date,Cast(OINM.DocDate as DATE)) > Convert(Date,'2014-05-01'))
    Where  OITM.ItmsGrpCod = @ItemGroup group by OINM.DocDate

    SET @i = @i + 1
    End

    It Gives 

    D  OpeningBalance Manufacture
    1  123            23

    D  OpeningBalance Manufacture
    2  143            773

    D  OpeningBalance Manufacture
    3  126            27
    .

    But I need it like

    D  OpeningBalance Manufacture
    1  123            23
    2  143            773
    3  126            27
    .
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a while loop? The reason you are getting multiple result sets is because you have a select inside a loop. Converting this to a set based approach will not only fix the issue it will be a lot faster.

Comment: I need loop because I have to check record for each date of the month.

Comment: That does NOT mean you need a loop. From the snippet you posted I don't see anything that indicates you need to process this RBAR (row by agonizing row).

Comment: Saying you "need it urgently" is a magnet for attracting negative feelings towards a question. What might be urgent for you, isn't for the community, we are here to help at our leisure, so your urgency is no concern for us.

Comment: How is it possible without adding any loop in it. Because I won't get records for each day.

Comment: You would use a numbers or tally table most likely. You only posted part of the code so it is impossible to offer much advice there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before loop:

```
create table #results (D int, OpeningBalance Int, Manufacture Int)
```

in loop

```
begin


insert into #results ...
select ...
end
```

--after

```
select * from #results
```

Comment: This solves the immediate issue nicely but unfortunately the looping is still happening. The best solution would be to get rid of the loop but the OP seems determined to keep the loop.